# When should we contact the editor to follow up on our submitted manuscript?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, editors, journal-workflow

We have submitted our manuscript for publication on June 18, 2020. Until now, we haven't heard any decision from the journal. The status of the manuscript on the online system is 'under review' since July 09, 2020 (this was updated twice). According to the journal's website, the review speed is 5.0 weeks for the first decision and 7.1 for the final decision. I am a bit confused if I should contact the editor or if I should wait until I receive an answer without contacting them. Do you recommend me contacting the editor in order to follow up on our manuscript? Most importantly, if yes, when should we contact the editor to follow up on our submitted manuscript? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, it's way too early for that. Calm down and be patient.**

The quoted averages are just that, averages. There are necessarily some pretty wide distributions around them, given that it may take the editor a while to find suitable reviewers, and then the reviewers have a couple of weeks to do their job (and many of them are routinely late). I would give it at least a month more before reaching out to the editor.

Additionally, there is a couple of points to consider:

- It's summer in most of the world, so everyone is on vacation (or "staycation") these days. That makes everything take a little longer than average.
- Everyone around the world is still a little distracted by the pandemic and the related work disruption, so long-term averages no longer match the current situation.

Comment: +1. I recently had someone contact the journal regarding a paper I was handling every few weeks starting about two weeks after submission. This comes across as very aggressive and is not appreciated by those handling the submission.